# discord.py - convert string into member, then move member into a specific channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

For my bot, I'm trying to make a command that will move a player from into a certain voice channel on the server from a string. The string is of the form 'ExampleUser#0000' and I am trying to convert the string into a member object and move them into a voice channel. I have imported the commands extension of discord.py and the command (currently not working) can be found below.

In future the string will come from a JSON I have and will only move certain members, but I want to get this sorted before I worry about that. For transparency, the JSON stores the author of a seperate command in a string as `f'{ctx.author}'` as well as some other information.

Any help to get this working would be appreciated.

```
name = 'ExampleUser#0000'
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name='Test')
    member = await MemberConverter().convert(ctx, name)
    await member.move_to(channel)
```

Comment: Is the problem converting the string to member?

Comment: What have you tried?  What errors did you get?  Can you verify that the command even runs?  You need to be a little more specific as it isn't completely clear what your issue is.  For starters though, you aren't using the `MemberConverter().convert()` function correctly, as it takes in a context and a name.  I advise that you read the documentation written here https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=memberconverter#discord.ext.commands.MemberConverter

Comment: The problem is converting the string to a member. I've found the correct function to move a member to a specific voice channel and edited the code above.

Comment: @FusionInsanity `MemberConverter()` does convert the string to a member, so if the code is not working, please also post any errors you are getting / the full stacktrace so we can help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the channel correctly your issue was with the member.

- [guild.get_member_named(NAMEHERE)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_member_named#discord.Guild.get_member_named)

You should use this fucntion to get the member by name, if you have the id use `guild.get_member(IDHERE)`. plus you can loop over them and use try/except in case someone is not connected.

```py
name = 'AZ#0573'

@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name='test')
    member = ctx.guild.get_member_named(name)
    await member.move_to(channel)
```